# Apache Camel Message Exchange - can you iterate over the exchange to produce multiple output files from a single message on in exchange

Tags: java, file, split, apache-camel

I have a single inbound message on the exchange. This message is split out in to multiple outbound files. The problem I see is that only the LAST file is produced. Logs show that we created successfully all the different files, however, can only write a single file to the exchange, the LAST file processed?  please tell me what I'm doing wrong Camelers.  thanks in advance!

setting the CamelFileName or the Exchange.FILLE_NAME

Logic that splits out the single file in to multiple files by placing the contents of a specific file in an ArrayList.
    ...

```
    log.info("Create output file for current asset: " + asset + " with fileName: " + fileName);
    StringBuilder ofsb = new StringBuilder();
    ofsb.append(outFolder).append("_").append(fileName).append("_").append(TimeStamp()).append(".csv");

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(baos);
    for (String row : serviceRecords) {
        out.writeBytes(row + System.lineSeparator());
    }
    out.flush();

      log.info("**** serviceRecords  " + " file name: " + fileName + "****");
      Iterator<String> pitr = serviceRecords.iterator(); //get the existing service records in array list
      while ( pitr.hasNext()) {
          String sRecord = pitr.next(); 
          log.info(pitr.next());
      }
    exchange.getOut().setHeader("CamelFileName", ofsb.toString());  //CamelFileName Exchange.FILE_NAME
    log.info("Asset File Name: " + exchange.getOut().getHeader("CamelFileName"));
    exchange.getOut().setBody(baos.toByteArray());
    baos.close();
    out.close();
    serviceRecords = new ArrayList<String>();
    sb = new StringBuilder();   
    ofsb = new StringBuilder(); 
    }
```

multiple files generated and written to file system based on a single inbound file on exchange.

this is a sample of the input file:  a previous a process collects all asset relationships, a tag is mapped to an asset.  all the tags that belong to a specific asset are made in to a collection.  The asset collection is put in an ArrayList.  It loops through all the assets related to this input file, creating an out file for each unique asset collection.

1548278588,G1.A_96BD1,1027.8129883,Float,GOOD
1548278590,G1.A_96BD1,1046.7722168,Float,GOOD
1548278591,G1.A_96BD1,1037.0013428,Float,GOOD
1548278596,G1.A_96BD1,1046.5593262,Float,GOOD
1548278598,G1.A_96BD1,1034.9998779,Float,GOOD

### THE QUESTION IS HOW DO YOU PRODUCE MULTIPLE FILES FROM A SINGLE EXCHANGE ???

I know something like this works but it is not in line with camel infra.
        ofsb.append(outFolder).append("*").append(fileName).append("*").append(TimeStamp()).append(".csv");
        File file = new File(dir, ofsb.toString());
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        CRLFPrintWriter out = new CRLFPrintWriter(fileWriter);
        for (String outputLine : serviceRecords ) {  //otemp, oServiceRecords, seviceRecords, osRecords
            out.println(outputLine);
        }

```
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    fileWriter.close();

    serviceRecords = new ArrayList<String>(); //reset serviceRecords record list of output records
    sb = new StringBuilder(); //reset record builder    
    ofsb = new StringBuilder(); //reset file name
    }
```

---- SNIPIT of Camel XML

```
<route autoStartup="true" id="core.fleet.asset.splitterRoute">
    <from id="_from4" uri="{{fileEnrichmentEndpoint}}"/>
    <process id="_process4" ref="assetCollectorProcessor"/>
    <process id="_process5" ref="fleetAssetSplitter"/>
    <to id="_splitOut" uri="{{fileSplitDestination}}"/>
</route>
```

Comment: What is `asset`, `serviceRecords`...? What your input message looks like? Please provide more details/code. Also, could you provide your camel route code as well?

Comment: Also, what is `TimeStamp()`? What lib? This file name is not necessarily unique `ofsb.append(outFolder).append("_").append(fileName).append("_").append(TimeStamp()).append(".csv");` especially If `TimeStamp()` is time in seconds.

Comment: asset is the name I call the tags within the file to be processed.

Comment: timestamp is exactly what it claims to be.  Yes the file is unique.  The fileName and the Timestamp change for each asset collection to be made in to a file.  a method that produces a timestamp

Comment: maybe I'm not asking this question very good.  How do you produce multiple files from a single file on exchange.  can an exchange be broken in to chunks?  is this possible on the exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the thing you ask (split a message and write parts to files), there is way too much Java code in this question.

Without reading your question in full detail, here is the **conceptional answer to your question**.

```
<route id="split">
    <from uri="[endpoint where full message arrives]"/>
    ...
    <split ...>
        ...
    </split>
    <to uri="direct:writeFiles"/>
</route>

<route id="writeFiles">
    <from uri="direct:writeFiles"/>
    <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
        <simple>...</simple>
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="file:directory?option=value"/>
</route>
```

The route "split" receives the message to split. You can do whatever you need (like your enrichment). At a certain point you use a [Splitter](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/split-eip.adoc) to **split the message into parts**.

After splitting you send the **individual message parts** (result of the splitter) to another route. In my example it is a direct route, but you can also use a message queue ([ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)) or an in-memory queue ([Seda](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html)).

The second route ("writeFiles") just receives the message parts and **saves them to files**. The [file component of Camel](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) simply writes the message body to a file.

Comment: thanks Burki, will need to rewrite code but I get it, thanks again

Comment: I have changed code to create an List of Lists.  then try to split this list of lists.  but, I'm having problems splitting a List of Lists.

Comment: You can use a JavaBean to implement the Splitter logic. If the standard Splitter cannot do what you want, you can tell him with a bean how to split the payload of your message. See here for an example: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/split-eip.adoc#using-a-pojo-to-do-the-splitting